# How do I insert a repeating, tiled image into the background of a WordPress page or post (not page background)?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

I have been *fiddling* with my [Pytheas theme](http://www.wpexplorer.com/pytheas-free-wordpress-theme/) again. This time, I am trying to insert a 2-color gif (suitable for tiling) onto the backgrounds of my pages and posts. Note that I do **not** mean the background of the whole page. That is, and should remain, black. The site/sample-post in question is [here](http://longgame.org/2012/02/95-hours-in-the-wasteland/).

I have investigated as extensively as I can given my coding deficiencies. Currently, I've been editing the **styles.css** file. I replaced *this* default code:

```
/* Body & Main
================================================== */
body { background: #eee url("images/main-bg.png") repeat; nowhitespace: afterproperty; font: 12px/1.8 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #444; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
body a { color: #f15a23 } /*main link color*/
body a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #000 }
```

with this *revised* code, which I cobbled together with my hazy understanding of CSS.

```
body {
  background: url("http://longgame.org/wp-content/uploads/grid-paper-2color-start.gif")  repeat; nowhitespace: afterproperty;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
  font: 12px/1.8 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #444; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
}
```

My thinking was that I needed that *rgba* bit to ensure that the color is transparent (in case the texture was 'behind' it). I don't know. I was throwing darts. Maybe it's in the wrong place. Maybe it's just flat out wrong. :)

I turn to you more qualified folks to help me out. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the CSS of your `body` element, try setting it on `#main-content`

Also, you only need the first line to achieve the effect you want:

```
#main-content {
    background: url("http://longgame.org/wp-content/uploads/grid-paper-2color-start.gif")  repeat;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That was ungodly fast. Thank you very much, metadept.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the background of the whole page to be affected, but only the background of the WordPress page/post, you shouldn't be adjusting the background properly of the `body` element in your CSS, which would affect the entire HTML page, but rather of the element for which you want to apply the background, probably `#main-content`.

Try setting that background property on `#main-content` near line 24 of your CSS file instead, e.g.

```
#main-content {
    background: url("http://longgame.org/wp-content/uploads/grid-paper-2color-start.gif")  repeat;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed you posted the correct method too. :) Thank you!